# Linux Expect Tutorial Example Questions

Tags: python, linux, expect

I am learning how to use the Linux command - Expect following [this tutorial](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/10/expect-examples/).

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

set timeout 20

spawn "./addition.pl"

expect "Enter the number1 :" { send "12\r" }
expect "Enter the number2 :" { send "23\r" }

interact
```

Can anyone here explain what the command below does.

```
spawn "./addition.pl"
```

btw, I cannot find any file called "./additon.pl", so I can not run the example successfully.

I don't know how this Perl was written, but I imagine somehow the script (as jvperrin mentioned, it could be any language) should read from standard input and add them up. 
I use Python and I tried to write the adder.py.

```
#!/usr/bin/python 
import sys
print int(sys.argv[1]) + int(sys.argv[2])
```

but when I change spawn "./add.py" it still doesn't work...

And the error looks like below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./add.py", line 3, in <module>
    print int(sys.argv[1]) + int(sys.argv[2])
IndexError: list index out of range
expect: spawn id exp7 not open
    while executing
"expect "Enter the number2 :" { send "23\r" }"
    (file "./test" line 8)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spawn will essentially start a command, so you could use it in any way you would a command. For example, you could use it as `spawn "cd .."` or `spawn "ssh user@localhost"` instead of as `spawn "./addition.pl"`.

In this case, the spawn directive starts an interactive perl program in `addition.pl` and then inputs two values to the program once it has started.

Here is my ruby program, which works fine with expect:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

print "Enter the number1 :"
inp1 = gets.chomp
print "Enter the number2 :"
inp2 = gets.chomp

puts inp1.to_i + inp2.to_i
```

Comment: I did not see the addition program in the tutorial... do you know Perl? is it hard to reverse engineer come up with the perl script used in the tutorial?

Comment: @B.Mr.W. The perl script isn't in the tutorial, but you could make the addition script in any language, it doesn't have to be Perl. I don't know Perl personally, but I know Ruby, and I could write an equivalent program with it if you would find that helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a C program to substitute the addition.pl.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    int a, b;
    printf("Enter the number1 :");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    printf("Enter the number2 :");
    scanf("%d", &b);
    printf("%d + %d = %d\n", a, b, a+b);
    return 0;
}
```

Two printf func call is necessary. :)